# Matlab: combining multiple matrices row-wise

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have some data in 10 matrices. Each matrix has a different number of rows, but the same number of columns.

I want to combine all 10 matrices to one matrix row-wise, interleaved, meaning the rows in that matrix will look like:

```
row 1 from matrix 0
...
row 1 from matrix 9
row 2 from matrix 0
...
row 2 from matrix 9
...
```

Example (with 3 matrices):

`Matrix 1: [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
Matrix 2: [3 2 1 ; 6 5 4]
Matrix 3: [1 1 1 ; 2 2 2 ; 3 3 3]
Combined matrix will be: [1 2 3 ; 3 2 1 ; 1 1 1 ; 4 5 6 ; 6 5 4 ; 2 2 2 ; 7 8 9 ; 3 3 3]`

Comment: You'll need a combination of `reshape` and `vertcat` or concatenation using `[ _ , _ ]` (horizontal) and `[ _ ; _ ]` (vertical)

Comment: I'm pretty new to matlab, and thus don't have much idea of how to start.
If you could post a code that does it so I can learn from it i'd appreciate it.

Comment: Provided example.

Comment: Well, the direct way would be to make all of the matrices the same size by padding with `NaN`s, combining, and then removing the `NaN` rows, but that feels like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the function `interleave2` here https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45757-interleave-vectors-or-matrices

```
z = interleave2(a,b,c,'row')
```

you can see the way the function works in the source code of course

Comment: Thanks, but matrix z is not combined row-wise, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general solution that allows you to place however many matrices you want (with matching number of columns) into the starting [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) `Result`:

```
Result = {Matrix1, Matrix2, Matrix3};
index = cellfun(@(m) {1:size(m, 1)}, Result);
[~, index] = sort([index{:}]);
Result = vertcat(Result{:});
Result = Result(index, :);
```

This will generate an index vector `1:m` for each matrix, where `m` is its number of rows. By concatenating these indices and [sorting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) them, we can get a new index that can be used to sort the rows of the [vertically-concatenated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) set of matrices so that they are interleaved.